# Как экспортировать план выполнения запроса Oracle на другу БД?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос, который на одной БД работает быстро, а на второй жутко тормозит. После анализа выяснено, что у запроса уехал план. Настроить план запроса хинтаим не получилось.

Как перенести хороший план запроса с одной БД на другую ?

Comment: Похоже, я не знаю какого то правильного слова, чтобы это нагуглить.

Comment: Я придумал слово для гугла, "export execution plan"  :) результат: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3898569?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для закрепления плана запроса использована технология [sql plan baseline](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_spm.htm#TGSQL94621).
Перенос выполнялся в несколько шагов.

На источнике:

1) Для нужного запроса получить `sql_id` и `plan_hash_value` конкретного плана.

2) Закрепить этот план на БД для запроса.

```
declare
  l_result number;
begin  
  l_result:= dbms_spm.load_plans_from_cursor_cache( 
                sql_id => 'g1gad19d2baa0', 
                plan_hash_value =>2051789865);
end;`
```

3) Создать таблицу для экспорта плана

```
begin
  dbms_spm.create_stgtab_baseline(table_name => 'table_name');
end;
```

4) Упаковать план для экспорта

```
declare
  l_result number;
begin
  l_result := dbms_spm.pack_stgtab_baseline(
                   table_name => 'table_name',
                   enabled =>'yes', 
                   creator => 'VIKTOROV_AA'); 
end;
```

5) Открепить план от запроса(если необходимо)

```
declare
  l_result number;
begin  
  l_result:= dbms_spm.drop_sql_plan_baseline(sql_handle => 'SQL_dc1fb582419833d4');
end;
```

`sql_handle` можно найти в таблице `dba_sql_plan_baselines`

На приемнике:

6)  Перетащить таблицу с планом с источника. Например через `DB_LINK`.

```
create table table_name as select * from table_name@db_link
```

7) Распаковать скопированный план и прикрепить к запросу

```
declare
 l_result number;
begin
  l_result := dbms_spm.unpack_stgtab_baseline(table_name => 'table_name');
end;
```